# Validating all entries in Input Boxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want a class in JavaScript through which I can validate all the Input Boxes on a form. I just want to supply the form name and it must validate the input boxes there in.

Is there any class or something other through which I can achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you looked at the validator plugin?

http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation

Comment: @meder: Looks great but I guess it is not Free.

Comment: Eh? ( and this is for the required char limit )

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use JQuery I described an alternative library in an earlier post
[What JavaScript library to use for client-side form checking?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/576631/what-javascript-library-to-use-for-client-side-form-checking/577633#577633)

That allows you to just add attributes like REQUIRED or DATE to an <INPUT> tag.

It's a bit old-hat now, but we are still using it in production :)